# How can i call a function 10 times every 2seconds and exit once it returns a true?

Tags: c#

I am using the following , just for testing at the moment

```
    public bool Retry(int numberOfRetries, Action method)
    {
        if (numberOfRetries > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                method();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogException(e);                   
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // retry
                return Retry(--numberOfRetries, method);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

         public void showMessage()
    {
        bool result = false;
        //result = true;
        if (result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("reached ", "reached", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I call it via the following:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Retry(10, showMessage);        
    }
```

But it says in the button4_Click event that showMessage is the wrong return type?
What i am wanting to do is call the function showMessage 10 times every 2 seconds and once it is true to exit.
I have forced it to be false because i am debugging and want to see it actually call it 10 times every 2 seconds
So basically i am trying to implement some Retry logic (call a function that returns a bool with a number of attempts and if unsuccessful then exit)

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Use a timer and a downcounter.

Comment: so the attempt above is not recommended ?

Comment: your issue is that you declared the showMessage as `void`, but you are returning a `bool`

Comment: ah yes  ..so obvious thanks

Comment: @Abbey Also you can use a loop and a downcounter with `Task.Delay` instead of recursion here, or a timer (bad idea being barely awake in fact here, although it depends on what you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your `showMessage` method is `void`, but you're trying to return a `bool`. Instead, use `public bool showMessage()`. A method defined as `void` cannot return anything.

Another thing to note is that you're never going to reach your `catch` block in order to retry, because nothing in your code is throwing an exception. Thus `Retry` will only execute once and it will return `true`. Instead, the `try` would probably go something like this:

```c#
try
{
    var result = method();
    if (!result)
    {
        throw new Exception("method returned false");
    }
    return true;    // Executes only if method() returns true
}
```

EDIT:

You'll also want to change `Action method` to `Func<bool> method`. An `Action` can accept zero or more parameters, but its return type must be `void`. A `Func` has a return type and zero or more parameters.